# Create a field instance programmatically on a taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm trying to create a module which creates a taxonomy vocabulary on installation of the module, and creates one text field on the taxonomy vocabulary/term. But I'm getting the following error when I enable my module:

> [error] FieldException: Attempt to create an instance of field field_flickr_photoset on forbidden entity type taxonomy_term. in field_create_instance() (line 468 of
>   /var/www/www.example.com/htdocs/modules/field/field.crud.inc).

First of al, why a Forbidden entity type? Is it not possible to create a field on a taxonomy vocabulary through code? Or am I missing some parameters?

I used very similar code to create a node type and attach fields to it, which currently works without any problems. I didn't think that changing the entity type would cause such problems.

I tried searching on google and here on how to do this, but all I get is people who are asking how to attach a taxonomy term reference field to a node type, which is not what I'm asking. It's attaching a text field to a taxonomy term/vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in [`taxonomy_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_entity_info/7) you'll see this code that defines the `taxonomy_vocabulary` entity type:

```
$return['taxonomy_vocabulary'] = array(
  'label' => t('Taxonomy vocabulary'),
  'controller class' => 'TaxonomyVocabularyController',
  'base table' => 'taxonomy_vocabulary',
  'entity keys' => array(
    'id' => 'vid',
    'label' => 'name',
  ),
  'fieldable' => FALSE,
);
```

The important bit to note is `'fieldable' => FALSE`...that's why it's 'forbidden' to add fields to that type.

The `taxonomy_term` entity type *is* fieldable so you won't have any problem adding field instances to one of those.

If you really want to add a field to the vocabulary, you'll need to implement [`hook_entity_info_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) to change the vocabulary entity to `'fieldable' => TRUE` (I've done it before, it's perfectly safe):

```
function MYMODULE_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['taxonomy_vocabulary']['fieldable'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that `taxonomy_vocabulary` and `taxonomy_term` were different entities. So thanks for this info. When I first written the code I set the `entity_type` for the field as `taxonomy_vocabulary` and enabled the module. And even after I disabled my module, it didn't remove the field from db, and it was still set as taxonomy_vocabulary entity type field in {field_config} table. So even after changing my code, and disabling re-enabling cc all-ing I was scratching my head. Now I deleted the record and re-enabled and now the field is created. Your info was very useful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 7**

If you check the code which causing that Exception, you'll see the following condition:

```
  // Check that the field can be attached to this entity type.
  if (!empty($field['entity_types']) && !in_array($instance['entity_type'], $field['entity_types'])) {
    throw new FieldException(t('Attempt to create an instance of field @field_name on forbidden entity type @entity_type.', array('@field_name' => $instance['field_name'], '@entity_type' => $instance['entity_type'])));
  }
```

That means the field which you're trying to define has restricted `entity_types` attribute which has list of entities to which the field can be attached.

So either you need to define your entity via the following property of your field:

```
  'entity_types' => array(0 => 'allowed_entity_type'),
```

leave it empty, or just try to remove `entity_types` attribute from the field definition at all.

---

Don't forget to clear the caches in Performance.

If the problem persist, you may try to remove the field to be able to recreate it again (e.g. `drush eval "field_delete_field('field_which_is_broken');"`).